# SQL Server: coalesce, prevent extra space?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Still learning SQL, how to prevent extra space in the result set between `FirstName` and `LastName`?

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO

SELECT FirstName + ' ' + COALESCE (MiddleName, '') + ' ' + LastName
FROM   Person.Contact;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

```
FirstName + ' ' + COALESCE (MiddleName + ' ', '') + LastName
```

Given that if `MiddleName` is `NULL`, so is `MiddleName + anything`

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO

SELECT FirstName +  COALESCE (' ' +MiddleName, '') + ' ' + LastName
FROM   Person.Contact;
```

if `MiddleName` is NULL `' '+MiddleName` becomes NULL and COALESCE returns the empty string, which prevents the extra space.

Comment: ha ha, this was the first of three nearly identical answers, yet it gets the fewest votes and is not the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

A null middle name plus a space will result in null, so:

```
FirstName + ' ' + COALESCE(MiddleName + ' ', '') + LastName
```

Should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I'd append the space within the `COALESCE()` function. Consider additionally handling the empty string:

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' 
          + COALESCE(NULLIF(MiddleName, '') + ' ', '') 
          + LastName
  FROM Person.Contact;
```